# Scanf no detecta enter (\n) al leer un array de unsigned char

Tags: c++, c, scanf

Estoy intentando leer una secuencia de, **como máximo**, 16 bytes en hexadecimal en C++. Por el funcionamiento del resto de mi código, necesito almacenar esa secuencia en un elemento definido de la siguiente forma:

```
//[...]
unsigned char *currentBlockState[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    currentBlockState[i] = new unsigned char[16];
}
//[...]
```

La secuencia se almacenaría, por ejemplo, en el primer elemento de dicho array.
A la hora de probar la lectura de datos de tamaño 16 fijo, me funciona bien usar lo siguiente:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i){
    scanf("%02hhx",&currentBlockState[0][i]);
}
```

Pero al querer que pueda leerme menos elementos, pero nunca pase de 16, y rellene el resto con ceros, nunca detecta el enter y queda esperando. He probado también las siguientes opciones, sin éxito:

```
scanf("%02hhx[^\n]",&currentBlockState[0][i]);
int x = scanf("%02hhx[^\n]%*c",&currentBlockState[0][i]);
```

¿Cómo podría implementarlo?

Comment: Por decir algo, no deberías implementar una función que previa a la lectura rellene el array con ceros?

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres leer una línea, lee una línea:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
```

Entonces analízala:

```
std::stringstream str(line);
for (int i = 0; str >> currentBlockState[0][i]; ++i) /* nada */;
```

Si quieres analizar lineas sin espacios, por ejemplo `abcdef => [0xab, 0xcd, 0xef]`:

```
char bytes[3];
char* endp;
for (int i = 0; str >> std::setw(2) >> bytes; ++i)
{
   currentBlockState[0][i] = std::strtol(bytes, &endp, 16);
   if (*endp) /* error */;
}
```

No uses `new`. En este caso, `std::array<unsigned char, 16>` es una buena elección.

Answer (score 0):

Logré resolverlo, al final cree un código aparte para leer como texto y convertir al formato que necesitaba. Dejo la solución que encontré por si alguien tiene la misma duda. No es la más eficiente, pero funcionó en mi caso:

```
std::cout << "Introduzca el bloque (en hexadecimal, sin espacios ni el 0x):";
std::string tmp = "", hextxt = "";
std::cin >> hextxt;
        
for(int j = 0; j < hextxt.length(); j+=2) {
    tmp.push_back(hextxt[j]);
    tmp.push_back(hextxt[j+1]);
    aux.push_back(tmp);
    tmp = "";
}
unsigned int c;
for(int j = 0; j < aux.size(); j++) {
    std::istringstream hexstr(aux[j]);
    hexstr >> std::hex >> c;
    bytes.push_back(c);
}
while(bytes.size() < 16) {
    std::istringstream hexstr("00");
    hexstr >> std::hex >> c;
    bytes.push_back(c);
}
for(int j = 0; j < bytes.size(); j++) {
    blocks[0][j] = bytes[j];
}
```